# Canvas draggable with kineticJS and Clip function

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I've a problem which deals with `canvas`.

I would like to use `kinetic` to use mobile events (most particularly for draggable) and I would also like to use the `clip()` function at the same time.

Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      canvas {
        border: 1px solid #9C9898;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="kinetic-v3.9.4.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: "container",
          width: 708,
          height: 500
        });
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        var circle1 = new Kinetic.Circle({
          x: 150,
          y: 150,
          radius: 75,
          fill: "red",
          draggable: true
        });

        var circle2 = new Kinetic.Circle({
          x: 350,
          y: 150,
          radius: 75,
          fill: "blue",
        });

        layer.add(circle2);
        layer.add(circle1);
        stage.add(layer);
      };

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onmousedown="return false;">
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've the first circle draggable but I would like to use it and the `clip function` but I don't really know how to do it. In addition, I tried to get the 2d context like this:

`var context = this.getContext();`

But it didn't work. If there's someone that can help me thanks.

I also saw this [example](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-clipping-regions/) but it doesn't work with mobile devices.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why the [example](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-clipping-regions/) you mentioned doesn't work on mobile is because its only using mouse event handlers:

```
stage.on("mousemove", function(){})
```

But you'll need to add touch events like this:

```
stage.on("mousemove touchmove", function(){})
```

**touchstart, touchmove, touchend**

Good luck!